# Getting Select value generated with AJAX with PHP

Tags: php, ajax, forms

I am very new to AJAX. I am trying to get the value of a select box generated by AJAX  from a PHP file. Let me give you an example what I am trying to do:

firstPage.html contains:

```
<form action="next.php" method="post">
<select name=cat id=cat onchange=load_sub_cat(this.value)>
<option value=0 selected=selected >Select Category</option>
<option id=1 value=1>A  </option>
<option id=2 value=2>B  </option>
<option id=3 value=3>C  </option>
</select>

<div id=sub_cat>---Select--Subcategory---</div>
<script>
function load_sub_cat(str){
                var xmlhttp;
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlhttp.open("get","getData.php?q="+str,false);
                xmlhttp.send();
                document.getElementById("sub_cat").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
</script>
```

getData.php contains:

```
<?php
$q=$_GET['q'];
//Some database calls……………………………
$html="<select name=sub>";
$html.="<option value=1>Test 1</option>";//Populating the options from database
$html.="</select>";
?>
```

At next.php I am trying to get the value submitted using the "sub" select box.
I have:

```
<?php
echo $_POST['cat'];
echo $_POST['sub'];
?>
```

I am getting the sub select box perfectly by selecting cat select box
But I do not get anything at $_POST['sub'] after submitting the form. I do get the $_POST['cat'].
Any help or tutorial link would be appreciated.

Comment: did you close your form tag properly?

Answer (score 0):

**1)** In your `getData.php`, you create the `$html` variable, but you don't appear to `echo` it to the browser.

```
...
...
$html.="</select>";
echo $html; // <-- echo it!
```

**2)** Your ajax is wrong. You can't instantly get the response text right after calling the `send()` method of the XHR. You need to listen on the `onreadystatechange` event:

```
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        document.getElementById("sub_cat").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
```

**3)** You need to wrap HTML attributes in quotes:

```
onchange="load_sub_cat(this.value)"
```

**4)** Looks like you are missing a closing `</form>` tag. Be sure to close the form **after** the `sub_cat` div, because that will contain a form input.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Yes I did close the form properly. As I have said before I can echo out the $_POST['cat'] but do not get anything from $_POST['sub_cat']

Comment: After I submit the form I get the following result:
1 // echo from $_POST['cat']
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: sub

Comment: is the `sub` dropdown showing now? You can watch the request in Firebug to see what is actually posted.

Comment: Yes the dropdown does show and work but the problem is that it is not posting the value with other form elements. I mean I can get other values like the cat dropdown and other input elements. But not the value of sub dropdown

Comment: Verify that the dropdown is within the form tag (not outside). Also watch the request in Firebug/Chrome dev tools to see what is actually posted.

Comment: Thanks MrCode for your help. The problem is fixed. I am using Codeigniter and don't know why but the form closed itself before the sub selectbox. But I double checked my code and the form_close() was written after it. The problem was identified when I checked the source code from Chrome browser. Anyways Thanks alot MrCode, vodich and Pablo

Answer (score 0):

Check you have closed the form html tag:
after ... 
put

Comment: Yes I did. I can echo out the $_POST['cat']